# Пытаюсь разобраться в циклах

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Вчера в универе, мы делали задачки (уже не помню какую) и чтобы не нажимать каждый раз на `F5`, я решил написать `while True`. Код примерно выглядел так:

```
while True:
    a = input()
    b = input()
    print(a+b)
```

Это увидел преподаватель и дал мне по морде. После чего сказал, что если будешь так писать, то тебя выгонят с работы. Я конечно понимаю, что `while True` нагружает оперативную память, но не знаю как по другому прописать цикл. Может возможно как то изменить на цикл `for`? Чем можно заменить `while True` и объясните.

Comment: Учитывая, что в основном тут поток будет висеть и ждать `input`, этот цикл ничего не нагружает. Единственная проблема - вы не предусмотрели условие выхода, выйти можно будет только по `Ctrl`+`C`. Так что тут только добавить `if` с `break`.

Comment: ну это просто пример, типа я пытался сделать так, чтобы не нажимать каждый раз F5. Можно ли как то заменить там while True @CrazyElf

Comment: Положите ваш код в функцию, ее запускайте в цикле. Когда будете сдавать преподу - убираете цикл. А так в этом коде ничего особо криминального нет.

Comment: Я это понимаю, просто хочу узнать на будущее, как можно заменить `while True` @insolor

Comment: Никак, оставьте как есть.

Comment: Это нормальный вполне вариант цикла, если будет условие выхода. Можно заменить, но будет больше строк кода, либо код будет повторяться, в этом нет смысла.

Comment: это жеско да...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Бесконечный цикл нужно прекратить командой `break` (которая исполнится при каком-то условии), например

```
while True:
    a = input()
    if a == "":   # когда пользователь нажмет только Enter, input() выдаст пустую строку,
        break     # и мы немедленно прекращаем работу цикла
    b = input()
    print(a+b)
```

---

*Замечание:*

Вы, вероятно, хотите сделать сумму из двух введенных **чисел**, а не соединить 2 **строки** (хотя и в виду чисел) в одну.

Ваш оригинальный код сделает из чисел 7 и 8 **не** 15, а **78**.

Тогда замените последнюю команду командой

```
    print(int(a) + int(b))         # когда вводятся только целые числа
```

или

```
    print(float(a) + float(b))     # когда вводятся любые числа
```

Comment: от души, спасибо что помогаешь изучить python

Answer (score 0):

Можно заменить на функцию:

```
def ABC():
    a = input() #Если нужно числа складывать, то int(input())
    b = input()
    print(a + b)

    c = input("Повторить?: ") #Просто жмёшь Enter, если хочешь повторить
    if c == "":
        return ABC()
    else:
        pass

ABC()
```

Comment: Ветвь `else:` излишняя, ее можно отбросить.